# Scope of the static member of .aspx class

Tags: asp.net

When I declare a `static` member in the code behind file of aspx class. For example

```
public partial class MyAspNetPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public static int IntVal;
}
```

As far as I know, the `static` member of a class is shared by all the instances of that class. How static member works in Asp.Net requests? The `IntVal` value is NOT shared among all the requests to the `MyAspNetPage` right? Can somebody explain and clarify? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any static variable in ASP.NET is shared among all requests and users of the application.

Comment: +1. side comment: to be more precise - among all requests handled by the same app domian. As result scoped to same server / IIS process (in case of web gardens).